# User sharing in Unix

Tags: permissions

How does Unix or Linux stop other users from accessing or modifying each others files? I know permissions are a part of it. Is there a specific concept in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept is the permissions concept.
To explain it, we first need to look at two things:
the uid and the filesystem.

### The uid

In Unix-like systems, every user has a User ID (UID)
in addition to the user name and other properties.
The uid is a number.
This uid can't be changed by the user itself.
You can check your user uid with the command

```
$ id
uid=1001(username) gid=1001(username) groups=1001(username)
```

The uid in this example output is 1001.
The uid is unique only on one operating system.
If you have two computers, two users can have the same uid.

### The filesystem

A Unix-like filesystem stores, for every file, the uid of the owner of the file and the permissions the owner has for this file, and much more.

You can see the permissions of a file if you execute

```
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r--  1 username  usergroup  1145 27 Feb 07:15 file
```

The permissions for the owner are "`-`**`rw-`**`r--r--`", so the owner can read the file and write to the file.

### How it all works

For the final understanding of the permission scheme, we need the kernel of the Unix system.

Every time we access a file or do something with a file, we don't touch the file directly. Instead we use a system call which asks the kernel to do the work for us.
Inside the system call, there are routines to get the uid of the user and to get the permissions of the file. The kernel then checks if the owner of the file is equal to the uid of the user; and if so, it then checks if the user has the needed permission.

The trick is that a normal user can't influence the kernel. The kernel is started in the boot process of the computer and then can be influenced only by the root user (with uid = 0).

The user can't change his uid, and he can't change permissions of a file he doesn't own (he would have to change his uid) because the kernel manages these things and only root can change them.

You can find more about permissions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) and more about system calls and how they work [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29#System_calls). And if you want to know what else is stored in the filesystem, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) about inodes.

### What I left out

This answer will give you only a small idea of the permission scheme, but I hope it will help you understand the things I left out better, like

- Groups, which work like the uid scheme
- Permissions for all users
- File types
- `sudo` and `su`
- Permissions over networks
- ... (If you want to know more, get a good book about operating systems.)

Comment: UIDs can be changed. `vipasswd` and a bunch of `chown -R`s (or a `find` if you're clever)

Comment: @strugee True! I edited the answer.